# Grails unit test for a domain class with constraint on relationship

Tags: hibernate, unit-testing, grails, mocking, entity-relationship

I have a domain class

```
class Door {
    String id
    String url
    Room room

    static hasOne = [lock: DoorLock]

    static mapping = {
        id generator: 'uuid'
    }

    static constraints = {
        url nullable:  false
        room nullable: true 
        lock nullable: true
    }
```

and I'm trying to write a simple Spock test for it (actually without any logic first, just to check mocking capabilities of Grails).

```
@TestFor(Door)
class DoorSpec extends Specification {
    protected void setup() {
       mockForConstraintsTests(Door)
    }

    def cleanup() {
    }

    void "test something"() {
       when:
       def door = new Door()

       then:
       true
     }
}
```

when I run the test (grails test-app Door) it fails with error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method on class [citypoints.Door] was used outside of a Grails application. If running in the context of a test using the mocking API or bootstrap Grails correctly.
    at citypoints.Door._clinit__closure2(Door.groovy:17)
    at org.grails.datastore.mapping.config.groovy.MappingConfigurationBuilder.evaluate(MappingConfigurationBuilder.groovy:80)
    at org.grails.datastore.mapping.config.AbstractGormMappingFactory.createMappedForm(AbstractGormMappingFactory.java:63)
    at org.grails.datastore.mapping.keyvalue.mapping.config.GormKeyValueMappingFactory.createMappedForm(GormKeyValueMappingFactory.java:39)
    at org.grails.datastore.mapping.keyvalue.mapping.config.GormKeyValueMappingFactory.createMappedForm(GormKeyValueMappingFactory.java:28)
    at org.grails.datastore.mapping.keyvalue.mapping.config.KeyValuePersistentEntity.<init>(KeyValuePersistentEntity.java:35)
    at org.grails.datastore.mapping.keyvalue.mapping.config.KeyValueMappingContext.createPersistentEntity(KeyValueMappingContext.java:95)
    at org.grails.datastore.mapping.model.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntities(AbstractMappingContext.java:174)
    at grails.test.mixin.domain.DomainClassUnitTestMixin.mockDomains(DomainClassUnitTestMixin.groovy:133)
    at grails.test.mixin.domain.DomainClassUnitTestMixin.mockDomain(DomainClassUnitTestMixin.groovy:166)
    at grails.test.mixin.domain.DomainClassUnitTestMixin.mockDomain(DomainClassUnitTestMixin.groovy:165)
    at org.spockframework.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:138)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.builtin.JUnitFixtureMethodsExtension$FixtureType$FixtureMethodInterceptor.intercept(JUnitFixtureMethodsExtension.java:145)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:84)
    at org.spockframework.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:138)
| Completed 1 unit test, 1 failed in 0m 3s
```

However when I remove the constraint `lock nullable: false` from the Door class, the test runs fine.

Is it a Grails bug or I do something wrong?

P.S. Tried to add `mockDomain(DoorLock)` before `mockForConstraintsTests(Door)` => nothing changes

P.P.S. I have Grails 2.3.7 and hibernate plugin ":hibernate:3.6.10.9"

Answer (score 0):

I found reproducible scenario for this error:
Error appears only when testing a domain class, which has a property (of any type) with the name 'lock' and a constraint against this property. 
Looks like Grails bug.